# Scala Doobie query hardcoded values

Tags: sql, scala, relational-database, doobie

When writing the following query in Doobie :

```
(SELECT id FROM (VALUES(?),(?),(?)) table(id))
UNION
SELECT id FROM table
```

I have list of data , e.g. List(1,2,3,4) that is **varied-size**.
How could I interpolate the list of values into SQL VALUES CLAUSE using Doobie?

Comment: You have three `?` for interpolation but a list of four values... can you give more detail on this?

Comment: I have varied-size list

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to have variable-length parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can refer below reference from doobie official community page:

```
Consider a below table DDL:     
CREATE TABLE country (
          code       character(3)  NOT NULL,
          name       text          NOT NULL,
          population integer       NOT NULL,
          gnp        numeric(10,2)
          -- more columns, but we won't use them here
    )
```

SQL using doobie syntax where codes is varied-size list:

```
sql"""
    select code, name, population, gnp 
    from country
    where code in (${codes : codes.type})
""".query[Country]
```

Comment: Can you link that community page, this gives me `type mismatch;` error ` required: doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment[_]`